# How to find the nearest values in 3 columns of 2 dataframes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have data in two dataframes as below:-

```
Df1
Container_width    Container_height       Container_depth
19.1    13.8    27.1
14.0    11.5    24.5
30.8    14.6    34.6
24.1    24.6    31.3
38.9    18.2    42.9
53.3    51.3    55.4
55.5    29.0    75.5
19.8    44.5    29.7


Df2
Item_width     Item_height      Item_depth
19.101496   11.497524   27.081574
19.094842   13.963226   26.889088
30.987301   14.600599   34.808122
38.522297   15.363778   56.248184
22.384495   15.291478   34.511771
30.801670   14.657632   34.703047
30.799078   14.495006   34.611856
22.829969   15.743264   31.294219
```

For every item in Df2 I want to find the nearest possible container dimensions in Df1.

Example:-

```
Item dimensions with : 30.987301    14.600599   34.808122
Should match : 30.8 14.6    34.6
```

Because all the dimensions of item are the nearest to all dimensions of container.

As per my research on stackoverflow I tried the sub,idxmin and abs functions but couldn't get result.

```
Df2['val'] = Df2.sub(Df1,axis=0).abs().idxmin(axis=1)
```

But with this approach I am getting NaN as result.

Second approach I tried is:-

```
Df2.sort_values('pred_height', inplace=True)
Df1.sort_values('container_size_height', inplace=True)
pd.merge_asof(Df2, Df1,left_on = 'pred_height', right_on='container_size_height')
```

But I am getting very vague results and I am not able to handle all 3 dimensions in this approach.

```
Ideal expected result would be:-
Item_width     Item_height       Item_depth Container_width Container_height Container_depth           
30.987301   14.600599   34.808122    30.8      14.6    34.6
```

Comment: How exactly do you define the _nearest possible container_? it is a distance (i.e. sqrt of sum of diffs)?

Comment: Yes we can go with this approach. I didn't have any specific approach in my mind though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
#cross join for merge both DataFrames together
df = Df2.assign(a=1).merge(Df1.assign(a=1), on='a', how='outer').drop('a', axis=1)

c1 = ['Container_width','Container_height','Container_depth']
c2 = ['Item_width','Item_height','Item_depth']

#get distance to new column
df['d'] = ((df[c2] - df[c1].values) ** 2).sum(axis= 1) ** .5

#get rows with minimal distance per groups
df = df.loc[df.groupby(c2)['d'].idxmin()]
print (df)
    Item_width  Item_height  Item_depth  Container_width  Container_height  \
8    19.094842    13.963226   26.889088             19.1              13.8   
0    19.101496    11.497524   27.081574             19.1              13.8   
32   22.384495    15.291478   34.511771             19.1              13.8   
56   22.829969    15.743264   31.294219             19.1              13.8   
50   30.799078    14.495006   34.611856             30.8              14.6   
42   30.801670    14.657632   34.703047             30.8              14.6   
18   30.987301    14.600599   34.808122             30.8              14.6   
28   38.522297    15.363778   56.248184             38.9              18.2   

    Container_depth          d  
8              27.1   0.266746  
0              27.1   2.302550  
32             27.1   8.242983  
56             27.1   5.939732  
50             34.6   0.105665  
42             34.6   0.118080  
18             34.6   0.279994  
28             42.9  13.651404
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Actually I created a multioutput ML model which gives the 'Item_width','Item_height','Item_depth' values as output. I have a test set of 6000 rows and for every row I get a set of item dimensions(Item_width','Item_height','Item_depth').

I have to find a container from the available containers in Df1. After the groupby step my output is reduced to 1891 records. Actually I would like my result to be 6000 records and every record has its item dimensions and container dimensions.

Comment: @Curious_Insider Not sure if understand, do you need `c1` like `df = df.loc[df.groupby(c1)['d'].idxmin()]
print (df)`

Comment: Actually I could get my results with your approach. But now if I have to choose first 3 minimum containers what can be the way? Choosing only 1 container gives me very less accuracy.

Comment: @Curious_Insider - Do you think `df.sort_values(c2 + ['d']).groupby(c2).head(3)` ?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I got my desired result.